# Android: How to share text on facebook without using dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I need to share text on facebook. I'm send text programatically through intent. In the below code snippet i need to share "**Lorem ipsum text to be shared**" text on facebook.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Lorem ipsum text to be shared");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Below screen is appearing before sharing the text.

[image]

can anyone help me share text on facebook without the window shown on above image?

Thanks & Regards,
Kamal

Answer (score 0):

You can´t and shouldn´t prefill the message:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

If you really need to share something without a dialog, you will have to authorize the User with `publish_actions` and use the API with the [/me/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed) endpoint.

Comment: Can CI share some thing without any permission

Comment: "CI"? what do you mean? no one can share something without any permission. why would you even want to do that anyway?

Comment: I can share link with intent , can I share text as well

Comment: what text? you can enter a text where it says "write something", check out your screenshot.